# My c++ program won't read multiple files from the command line

Tags: c++, matrix, command-line, command-line-arguments, matrix-multiplication

I have a c++ program that is meant to read two files representing matrices. It will only read in one of the files. Both files just contain a matrix of floats. The program is meant to read in two matrices and multiply them together and print out the result to the command line. Here is the code for the program.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ofstream;

#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readArr(int, int, double **);
void multArrs(int, double **, int, double **, int, double **);
void printResult(int, double **, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //read in the number of rows and columns
  int ar = atoi(argv[1]);
  int ac = atoi(argv[2]);
  int br = atoi(argv[3]);
  int bc = atoi(argv[4]);

  if (ac != br)
  {
    cerr<< "Matrix dimensions mismatch; exiting.\n";
    exit(-1);
  }

  // reserve space for the three arrays
  double **A = new double*[ar]; // each el. of this points to a row of A
  for (int i = 0; i < ar; i++)
    A[i] = new double[ac];  // a row of 'ac' floats

  double **B = new double*[br];
  for (int i = 0; i < br; i++)
    B[i] = new double[bc];  // a row of 'bc' floats

  double **C = new double*[ar];
   for (int i = 0; i < ar; i++)
    C[i] = new double[bc];  // each el. of this points to a row of C

  readArr(ar, ac, A);
  readArr(br, bc, B);
  multArrs(ar, A, bc, B, ac, C);
  printResult(ar, C, bc);


}
//read in the matrix from the command line
void readArr(int r, int c, double **arr)
{
for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
        std::cin>> arr[i][j];
        cout << " \n" << arr[i][j];
    }
}
}

void multArrs(int ar, double **A, int bc, double **B, int br, double **C)
{
    for(int i=0; i<ar; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<bc; ++j)
    for(int k=0; k<br; ++k)
    {
        C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }
}

void printResult(int r1, double **C, int c1)
{
cout << endl << "Output Matrix: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<r1; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<c1; ++j)
    {
        cout << " " << C[i][j];
        if(j==c1-1)
            cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The program is ran with the following command : `./matmult 3 3 3 3 <matrix1 <matrix2`
It will only read in matrix2 and places it in the first double array and then the second double array just contains 0's. The matrix file looks like this:

```
2.0 3.0 1.0
6.0 2.0 2.0
7.0 3.0 5.0
```

Thanks for any insight ye can provide. I have tried searching for an answer but I can't find one. Also the matrices have to be read in using < matrix1

Comment: Where are you reading from a file?  `readArr()` is reading in from `cin`

Comment: @NathanOliver cin reads in the file but it only reads in the one file

Comment: @SeanRyan That is the incorrect way. Pass the filename as arguments and read the files using `ifstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way you can pass only one input file, because it is redirect of standard input. So this is why program reads only second matrix, because it read only last statement. Please use file names as arguments and open files in source code or merge two files into one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using shell specific features for this, the two redirects after each other it would be good to know what OS and what shell you are using. I would instead use the file names as arguments and open the files from within the program.